# Extracted variance is above 1 (CCA and redundancy analysis)

Tags: scikit-learn, canonical-correlation, redundancy-analysis

I tried to repeat the analysis from Stewart and Love 1968, to compute the Variance Extracted and redundancy index from CCA. Based on their paper (if I followed it correctly), Variance Extracted  per canonical correlation $R_c$ is $\sum_{i=0}^{L}(p_i^2)/L \times R_c ^2$, where $p_i$ is a loading component and L is the length of the loading. For the smaller dataset the extracted variance is supposed to be 1 (or 100%) as the dimensionality does not change. However, I got a problem because my loadings are much bigger then 1 (like 3000) for the first components, hence, the explained variance is far above 1.

I used X of shape (7000, 128) and Y of shape (7000, 32) and projected to 32 dimensions.
Here is the code I have used

```
import dumpy as np 
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import CCA

dim = 32
cca = CCA(n_components=dim)
cca.fit(X, Y)
X_train_r, Y_train_r = cca.transform(X, Y)
corr = np.corrcoef(X_train_r.T, Y_train_r.T)

canonical_correlations = []
cc_squared_lambda = []
for i in range(dim):
    canonical_correlations.append(corr[dim + i][i] )
    cc_squared_lambda.append(
        (corr[dim + i][i] ) * (corr[dim + i][i] )
    )
    
ve_x = [sum(cca.x_loadings_.T[i] ** 2) / len(cca.x_loadings_.T[i]) for i in range(dim)]
ve_y = [sum(cca.y_loadings_.T[i] ** 2) / len(cca.y_loadings_.T[i]) for i in range(dim)]
```

Standardisation with

```
from scipy.stats import zscore
X = zscore(X,ddof=1)
```

does not change anything

The loading example is here:

```
cca.y_loadings_.T[0]
array([  6631.90255789, -20089.44073646,  24966.82137428, -17472.53659417,
       -18221.01590917, -10419.99286959, -18827.78182335,   -920.64755629,
         6350.3504796 ,  19091.6876097 ,  20601.59701128, -23153.96945065,
         7172.76198198,   6727.43734442,  -8236.01820536,  19203.38971974,
         5139.47048927, -16393.65319585,  -2521.8647585 , -25269.42170858,
       -21303.08870837, -17103.39536595, -16719.21073426,   6063.37755252,
       -25200.72626919, -10409.71743587,  24201.955096  , -32194.07699544,
       -12877.95758811,  12650.16532332,  26514.62449084, -13123.78644931])
```

In all of the example I found for redundancy analysis the loadings components magnitude was less then 1, however, I do not understand why it should be limited to this.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that loadings do not have a common definition. In scikit-learn they are the regression coefficients from PLS, hence, can be above 1, however, in the the paper they used correlations between original features and features in the latent space as loadings (L is the loading vector, correlation of k-th latent dimension with j-th original feature)

[image]

Hence, instead of using `cca.x_loadings_`, I needed

```
cca = CCA(n_components=dim)
cca.fit(X, Y)
X_t, Y_t = cca.transform(X, Y)

loadings_x = np.zeros((X.shape[-1], dim))
loadings_y = np.zeros((Y.shape[-1], dim))

for i in range(X.shape[-1]):
    for j in range(dim):
        loadings_x[i][j] = np.corrcoef(X[:, i], X_t[:, j])[0, 1]
        
for i in range(Y.shape[-1]):
    for j in range(dim):
        loadings_y[i][j] = np.corrcoef(Y[:, i], Y_t[:, j])[0, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you for following up and answering your own question! Future readers should find this helpful.

Comment: BTW, welcome to CV, Polina. Hope you would contribute more here.